# Build Failed Error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

When i try to run my project ,i am getting a build failed error.
It says  this:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/anushapachunuri/Desktop/Views/RestKit/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Data", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestScreenThirdViewController.o
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely calling out to files that aren't in your project. Have a look at the file that is highlighted. What files is it including? What, if any, other frameworks does it depend on?

You actually need to have the files in the Xcode project, not just on disk for the compiler to know about them.